# Date no postgresql.PL/SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

com a função abaixo quero fazer com que essa função compare a data atual com a data armazenada no banco.POREM ,NAO ESTA HAVENDO RETORNO .

```
create table mercado(

    id integer,
    diaEntrega date,
    valor integer    
);

insert into mercado values (2,'7-02-18',12); 

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_d () RETURNS date AS    
$$    
DECLARE    
        dataAtual date;
        varValor integer;
        dataFinalizada date;                       
BEGIN    
     SELECT CURRENT_DATE INTO dataAtual;            
     /*SELECT diaEntrega FROM mercado WHERE '7-02-18' = diaEntrega INTO  dataFinalizada;*/ /*OBS:DESTA FORMA FUNCIONA*/          

     SELECT diaEntrega FROM mercado WHERE dataAtual = diaEntrega INTO dataFinalizada;

     return  dataFinalizada;        
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Comment: Qual erro lhe é apresentado?

Comment: NA VERDADE NÃO É PROPRIAMENTE UM ERRO.O RETORNO DA FUNÇÃO NAO ESTA RETORNANDO NADA QUANDO NA VERDADE ERA PRA RETORNAR .O PROBLEMA É A COMPARAÇÃO QUE FAÇO DE dataAtual = diaEntrega QUE NAO ESTASENDO FEITA .NAO SEI COMO CONSERTAR.

Comment: e sua tabela mercado, tem dados para o dia atual?

Comment: não !!!! eu siplesmente quero comparar a data atual aque obtenho com esta função  SELECT CURRENT_DATE  com este valor  retornado  do banco '7-02-18' porém, a comparação não esta sendo feita.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não retorna nada porque a data na tabela é 18-02 e hoje são 17-02. De qualquer forma assim é muito mais simples:

```
create or replace function get_d ()
returns setof date as $$
    select diaEntrega
    from mercado
    where current_date = diaEntrega
    ;
$$ language sql;
```

Veja que você tem que retornar `setof` porque pode haver mais de uma data. Você vai precisar derrubar (`drop`) a sua função antes de criar esta nova porque ela muda o tipo de retorno.

Comment: verdade mano !! distração minha !vou usar essa forma que vc fez!obrigado